# How to check convergence of mixed logit model?

Tags: logit, mlogit

I have estimated mixed logit model using data collected from 69 respondents. each respondents have faced 4 repeated choice scenario. I have 7 variables. in the model, 5 variables are assumed to be normally distributed, 1 censored normal and 1 log normal. I have estimated mixed logit model using Bayesian approach (using program code provided by K. Train).

How can I check whether model converge successfully or not